# How can I split a string between multiple delineating characters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, parsing, .net-3.5, string

I'm working on a program that will parse off chunks off data from a CSV file, and populate it into the attributes of an XML document. The data entry I'm working with looks like this...e11*70/157*1999/101*1090*04.  I want to break that up, using the asterisks as the reference to split it into e11, 70/157, 1999/101, etc; so I can insert those values into the attributes of the XML.  Would this be a situation appropriate for RegEx?  Or would I be better off using Substring, with an index of *?

Thanks so much for the assistance.  I'm new to the programming world, and have found sites such as these to be a extremely valuable resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `String.Split()`

```
string[] words = @"e11*70/157*1999/101*1090*04".Split('*');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful.  I should be able to pull out those split values from the string array, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your ptoblem :

```
string content = @"11*70/157*1999/101*1090*04";
     string [] split = words.Split('*');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, RaM, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method to create a string array like so:

```
string txt = "e11*70/157*1999/101*1090*04";
foreach (string s in txt.Split('*')){
   DoSomething(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the assist McMinton, I really appreciate it.