# How to split string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

In the following example,

```
/*----------------------// kvkbl jk//bv klb /* /*gkljbgflkjbncviogf*/
```

how do I get the strings between `/*` and `*/`?

Comment: Why not just use string.Split? Regex is overkill for this.

Comment: What's your desired return value? (a) `---...ogf` or (b) `gkl...ogf` or something else?

Comment: Which of the 3 `/*` do you want to start at?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951114/how-can-i-split-a-string-between-multiple-delineating-characters

Comment: Thanks for the sample input, but unfortunately we can't do much with it until you give us what the output should be. Can you edit your questions and add what the output should be, given that input string. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to "split" the string? Maybe you want to remove/extract parts of it? Splitting a string ofter results in empty strings between tokens, for example.

Comment: Anbarasu - I'm voting to close your question. I don't think I can be answered in this form, until you provide your expected output, and preferably some more examples (try to think of edge cases, like string literals, or escaped characters).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split)

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "/*there*/ is a cat";
        string s = "User name (sales)";
        int start = s.IndexOf("/*");
        int end = s.IndexOf(")*/")
        string result = s.substring(start, end - start -1)
        //result contains "there"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow identical answer in a span of 10 mins !

Comment: I at least given source where I ... borrowed it. Poster before me stolen it

Comment: Actually the OP wanted strings, not a single one :P

Answer (score -1):

```
string s = "there is a cat";
    //
    // Split string on spaces.
    // ... This will separate all the words.
    //
    string[] words = s.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }



   //Output 
     there
     is
     a
     cat
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful. You've probably missed the edit, but the poster wants to "split" (?) on `/*`...`*/`, not a simple string/character.